# SQL - I need to divide a total value into multiple rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlite

Lets say I have the following tables in SQL server 2008

School Table

```
School_Id |Course_Id | Total Students | 
--------------------------------------- 
   1         Acct101        150
   1         Acct102        100
   2         Acct101        110
   2         Acct102        130
```

Class Table

```
School_Id |Course_Id | Class_ID | Capacity
--------------------------------------- 
   1         Acct101     A1       65
   1         Acct101     A2       50
   1         Acct101     A3       70
   1         Acct102     Ab1      100
   1         Acct102     Ab2      100
   2         Acct101     B1       80
   2         Acct101     B2       90
```

Based on the given information, I need to display total students per class as follow:

```
    School_Id |Course_Id | Class_ID | Capacity | Students 
    ------------------------------------------------- 
       1         Acct101      A1        65        60
       1         Acct101      A2        45        40
       1         Acct101      A3        70        50
       1         Acct102      Ab1       100       70
       1         Acct102      Ab2       100       30
       2         Acct101      B1        80        60
       2         Acct101      B2        90        50
```

I got the students value in the first 3 rows based on the total students value in the first row in school table which is 150

So I divide 150 into 3 classes and took class capacity into consideration while dividing.
(I just need any compinations of numbers that make my total within class limit. Also, all class rooms must have students, so zero student in a class is not acceptable)

How can I acheive this ?

Please Note that I have a table with +500,000 rows and another one with totals summary values, so I need to plug in values in the first table based on the totals summary.

Comment: What is the basis of didvidng the rows like you have done for acct01 and school id 1 i.e. 60,40 and 50.

Comment: I have a total of 150 students in Acct 101 in school 1, and I need to divide this number by 3 classes. I don't care what numbers are they, since they make my total of 150 and don't exceed the class cap.

Comment: So the basis would be dividing the total students by the number of classes with the condition that the number must be equal or less than class limit.

Comment: Then why not fill it with full capacity say 65,45 and 40 instead of 60,40,50..You have to have some kind of dividing logic and then it will be easier to do

Comment: It's ok to fill it with full capacity. I still stuck with it, I don't even know how to start or from where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, this query first populates classrooms with greatest capacity:

```
DECLARE @School TABLE (School_Id INT,Course_Id 
    VARCHAR(50), Total_Students INT)
DECLARE @Class TABLE (School_Id INT,Course_Id 
    VARCHAR(50), Class_ID VARCHAR(50), Capacity INT)
INSERT @School VALUES 
   (1,         'Acct101'        ,150),
   (1,         'Acct102'        ,100),
   (2,         'Acct101'        ,110),
   (2,         'Acct102'        ,130)
INSERT @Class VALUES 
   (1,         'Acct101'     ,'A1'       ,65),
   (1,         'Acct101'     ,'A2'       ,50),
   (1,         'Acct101'     ,'A3'       ,70),
   (1,         'Acct102'     ,'Ab1'      ,100),
   (1,         'Acct102'     ,'Ab2'      ,100),
   (2,         'Acct101'     ,'B1'       ,80),
   (2,         'Acct101'     ,'B2'       ,90)

;WITH y AS (
SELECT  a.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY a.School_ID, a.Course_ID ORDER BY a.Capacity DESC) 
            CapacitiyOrderPerSchoolAndCourse,
        SUM(a.Capacity) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY a.School_ID, a.Course_ID) 
            TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse,
        b.Total_Students TotalParticipants
FROM    @Class a
JOIN    @School b ON 
        b.School_Id = a.School_Id
        AND b.Course_Id = a.Course_Id
), z AS(
SELECT  x.School_Id, 
        x.Course_Id, 
        y.TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse, 
        y.TotalParticipants,
        CASE WHEN y.TotalParticipants < SUM(x.Capacity) THEN 
                y.TotalParticipants
            ELSE 
                SUM(x.Capacity) 
            END NumberOfStudentsInClasses,
        MIN(y.Capacity) ClassCapacity,
        y.Class_ID ClassName,
        MIN(y.Capacity) - 
        CASE WHEN y.TotalParticipants - SUM(x.Capacity) < 0 THEN 
               ABS(y.TotalParticipants - SUM(x.Capacity))
            ELSE
               0
            END StudentsInClass
FROM    y
JOIN    y x ON x.School_Id = y.School_Id 
        AND x.Course_Id = y.Course_Id 
        AND x.CapacitiyOrderPerSchoolAndCourse 
                <= y.CapacitiyOrderPerSchoolAndCourse
GROUP   BY x.School_Id, 
        x.Course_Id, 
        y.CapacitiyOrderPerSchoolAndCourse, 
        y.Class_ID, 
        y.TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse, 
        y.TotalParticipants
)

SELECT  
        z.School_Id, 
        z.Course_Id, 
        z.TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse, 
        z.TotalParticipants,
        z.ClassName,
        z.ClassCapacity,
        CASE WHEN StudentsInClass < 0 THEN 
                0 
            ELSE 
                StudentsInClass 
            END StudentsInClass
FROM    z
```

If you want each classroom to have some number of students you can do it like this (it allocates a number of students to each classroom according to it's capacity):

```
;WITH y AS (
SELECT  a.*,
        SUM(a.Capacity) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY a.School_ID, a.Course_ID) 
            AS TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse,
        b.Total_Students TotalParticipants
FROM    @Class a
JOIN    @School b ON 
        b.School_Id = a.School_Id
        AND b.Course_Id = a.Course_Id
), z AS(
SELECT  y.School_Id, 
        y.Course_Id, 
        y.TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse, 
        y.TotalParticipants,
        MIN(y.Capacity) ClassCapacity,
        y.Class_ID,
        MIN(y.Capacity) * 1.0 / y.TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse 
            AS PercentOfCapacity,
        ROUND(
            MIN(y.Capacity) * 1.0 / y.TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse 
                * TotalParticipants
            , 0, 0) 
            AS NumberOfStudents
FROM    y
GROUP   BY y.School_Id, 
        y.Course_Id, 
        y.Class_ID, 
        y.TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse, 
        y.TotalParticipants
)
, i AS(
SELECT  
        z.School_Id, 
        z.Course_Id, 
        z.TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse, 
        z.TotalParticipants,
        z.Class_ID,
        z.ClassCapacity,
        PercentOfCapacity,
        NumberOfStudents,
        SUM(NumberOfStudents) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY z.School_Id, z.Course_Id) 
            AS SumNumberOfStudents,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY z.School_Id, z.Course_Id 
                ORDER BY NumberOfStudents) 
            AS ClassWithSmallestCapacity
FROM    z
), j AS(
SELECT  i.School_Id, 
        i.Course_Id, 
        i.TotalCapacityForSchoolAndCourse, 
        i.TotalParticipants,
        i.Class_ID,
        i.ClassCapacity,
        i.PercentOfCapacity,
        i.NumberOfStudents,
        i.NumberOfStudents +
        CASE WHEN ClassWithSmallestCapacity = 1 THEN 
                TotalParticipants - SumNumberOfStudents 
            ELSE 0 
            END AS NumberOfStudents2
FROM    i
)

SELECT  *
FROM    j
```

Comment: This works fine but in this case some classes will have 0 student. There must be students in each class room.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: @user1542186: this sounds like a new requirement (your question states "I just need any compinations [sic] of numbers that make my total within class limit").  Please edit your question to reflect that 0 students in a class is not acceptable, so that people can give you helpful answers.

Comment: This query is what I'm looking for. It works perfectly for my situation.
Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you go ahead with full capacity then you might miss one or more classes.But in that case you could do running total till you reach say 150 in case of your example.But for second class you have capacity as 100 and total student are 100 so only calls 1 will be filled and class 2 will have 0 student.This is easier method.

Other method is that you get the ration of total student i.e. 150 and total capcty i.e. 180 and use this ratio to multiply with each row to get the student for each class but the issue here is that for some classes you might get the fractions values which are not possible and thus you have to use round or ceiling but these will cause 1 or 2 students missing depending what is the total fraction for each row. This is tricky one and with so many rows it could be much more tricky.

EDIT : Adding the second method here..
try this..

```
select cs.*,round(cs.capacity*rt.ratio,0) from
(
select cp.*,sc.totalstudents/cp.cap as ratio
from (select schoolid,courseid,sum(capacity) cap from class ) as cp
inner join 
school sc on cp.schoolid = sc.schoolid and sc.courseid = cp.courseid
) rt
inner join class cs 
on cs.schoolid = rt.schoolid and rt.courseid = cs.courseid
```

This should work approaximately but might miss something or have extra student.This should be quite efficient as well based on the indexes.

You could use NTILE as well but that could hamper the performance as each row will be joined with a numbers table using a nesteed loop join most probably.

Comment: The second method would work, I just need an approximate number to the total. What do you suggest to do in order to start working on this method?

Thank you so much, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Msg 189, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The round function requires 2 to 3 arguments.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'rt'.

Comment: changed the query..just add ,0 in round

Comment: Also, can you post the proper ddl for these tables and at least 10 rows for first table and all the related rows for second table. Then It will be easier to provide the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to use your own tables and logic based on this.Ntile with cursor will return perfect data and should be quiet fast as well.You need a numbers table as well for this method.

```
set nocount on
go
drop table soh
go
select salesorderid,round(totaldue -10,0)%180 totaldue into soh
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
go
create unique clustered index idx_soh_id on soh(salesorderid) 
go
drop table sod
go
select salesorderid,salesorderdetailid,round(linetotal,0)%200 as linetotal  into sod
from sales.SalesOrderDetail
go
create unique clustered index idx_sod_id on sod(salesorderid,salesorderdetailid) 
go
drop table #sod
go
declare @salesorderid int,@totaldue float,@cnt int,@sm float
declare cr_cursor cursor fast_forward 
for select salesorderid ,totaldue from soh
select salesorderid,salesorderdetailid, linetotal,0 as val,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by salesorderid order by linetotal asc) as rn 
into #sod from sod
create unique clustered index idx_#sod on #sod(salesorderid,salesorderdetailid)
open cr_cursor
while(1=1)
begin
    fetch cr_cursor into @salesorderid,@totaldue
    if (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0)
    begin
        break
    end
    select @sm =sUM(linetotal) ,@cnt = COUNT(salesorderdetailid) 
    from #sod where salesorderid = @salesorderid
    ;with cte as 
    (select @salesorderid salesorderid,nt,count(*) cnt from 
    (select NTILE(@cnt) over( order by n.cnt asc) nt from nums n where n.cnt <= @sm - @totaldue ) dta
    group by nt
    )
    update s 
    set val = c.cnt
    from #sod s inner join cte c on s.SalesOrderID= c.salesorderid and s.rn= c.nt
end
close cr_cursor
deallocate cr_cursor

select * from #sod
go
```