# Dividing a sum value into multiple rows due to field length constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

I am migrating financial data from a very large table (100 million+ of rows) by summarizing the amount and insert them into summary table. I ran into problem when the summary amount (3 billions) is larger than what the field in the summary table can hold (can only hold up to 999 millions.)  Changing the field size is not an option as it requires a change process.

The only option I have is to divide the amount (the one that breach the size limit) into smaller ones so it can be inserted into the table.

I came across this [SQL - I need to divide a total value into multiple rows in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589821/sql-i-need-to-divide-a-total-value-into-multiple-rows-in-another-table) which is similar except the number of rows I need to insert is dynamic.

For simplicity, this is how the source table might look like

account_table

```
acct_num   |      amt
-------------------------------
   101         125.00
   101         550.00
   101         650.00
   101         375.00
   101         475.00
   102          15.00
   103         325.00
   103         875.00
   104         200.00
   104         275.00
```

The summary records are as follows

```
select acct_num, sum(amt) 
from account_table
group by acct_num
```

Account Summary

```
acct_num   |      amt
-------------------------------
   101        2175.00
   102          15.00
   103        1200.00
   104         475.00
```

Assuming the maximum value in the destination table is 1000.00, the expected output will be

summary_table

```
acct_num   |      amt
-------------------------------
   101        1000.00
   101        1000.00
   101         175.00
   102          15.00
   103        1000.00
   103         200.00
   104         475.00
```

How do I create a query to get the expected result?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select acct_num, sum(amt) /10000`. Later just don't forget to multiply by 10000 to get money back

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't get how the query above will return the expected result based on the source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a numbers table.  If you have a handful of values, you can define it manually.  Otherwise, you might have one on hand or use a similar logic:

```
with n as (
      select (rownum - 1) as n
      from account_table
      where rownum <= 10
     ),
     a as (
      select acct_num, sum(amt) as amt
      from account_table
      group by acct_num
     ) 
select acct_num,
       (case when (n.n + 1) * 1000 < amt then 1000
             else amt - n.n * 1000
        end) as amt
from a join
     n
     on n.n * 1000 < amt ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  That's what I needed.<p>

The result actually return everything as 1000.  I tweaked the condition to return the result I need.

(case when (n.n + 1) * 1000 < amt then 1000

Answer (score 0):

A variation along these lines might give some ideas (using the 1,000 of your sample data):

```
WITH summary AS (

  SELECT acct_num
        ,TRUNC(SUM(amt) / 1000) AS times
        ,MOD(SUM(amt), 1000) AS remainder
    FROM account_table
    GROUP BY acct_num

), x(acct_num, times, remainder) AS (

  SELECT acct_num, times, remainder
    FROM summary

  UNION ALL

  SELECT s.acct_num, x.times - 1, s.remainder
    FROM summary s
        ,x
    WHERE s.acct_num = x.acct_num
      AND  x.times > 0

)
SELECT acct_num
      ,CASE WHEN times = 0 THEN remainder ELSE 1000 END AS amt
  FROM x
  ORDER BY acct_num, amt DESC
```

The idea is to first build a summary table with div and modulo:

```
ACCT_NUM    TIMES   REMAINDER
101         2       175
102         0       15
103         1       200
104         0       475
```

Then perform a hierarchical query on the summary table based on the number of "times" (i.e. rows) you want, with an extra for the remainder.

```
ACCT_NUM    AMT
101         1000
101         1000
101         175
102         15
103         1000
103         200
104         475
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Initially that's how I started.  I got the number of times and the remainder and not sure how to proceed.  I never used hierarchical query and this is extremely helpful.