# How do I split a duration of time into hourly intervals in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an input table of the login and logout hours of users in a table, I am required to split the output into hourly  intervals.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

here's the snippet to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    userid varchar(255),
    date_capture DATE,
    login_hour int,
    logout_hour int
);
```

here's the test data:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(userid,date_capture,login_hour,logout_hour)  
       VALUES  ('Test1', '02-JUN-2020',6,9);
INSERT INTO table_name  (userid,date_capture,login_hour,logout_hour)
       VALUES  ('Test2', '02-JUN-2020',3,4);
```

Here is the expected output:

[image]

Comment: The request here is to split the second row for `userid` 'xyz' into 3 rows with 1 hour for each session. 1 - 2, 2 -3 and 3 - 4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - I need to divide a total value into multiple rows in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589821/sql-i-need-to-divide-a-total-value-into-multiple-rows-in-another-table) even though it SQL Server, the approach should be the same while syntax may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cte to recursively add an hour until the target is reached:

```
with cte(userid,date_capture,login_hour,logout_hour,target) as (
      select userid, 
             date_capture, 
             login_hour, 
             login_hour + 1, 
             logout_hour
      from   table_name
      union all
      select userid, 
             date_capture, 
             logout_hour, 
             logout_hour + 1, 
             target
      from   cte
      where  logout_hour + 1 <= target
)
select   userid, 
         date_capture, 
         login_hour, 
         logout_hour
from     cte
order by userid,
         date_capture, 
         login_hour;
```

Comment: this worked perfectly , I only needed to add the column names after the WITH CTE declaration and clean up the ordering:

Comment: with cte (userid,date_capture,login_hour,logout_hour,target) AS 
(
      select userid, 
             date_capture, 
             login_hour, 
             login_hour + 1 as logout_hour, 
             logout_hour as target
      from   table_name
      union all
      select userid, 
             date_capture, 
             logout_hour, 
             (logout_hour + 1), 
             target
      from   cte
      where  logout_hour + 1 <= target
)
select userid, 
       date_capture, 
       login_hour, 
       logout_hour
from   cte
order by userid,login_hour;

Comment: Alright, the field list should be optional when the inner query has the desired column aliases. Any way, I updated the answer with it, and added the order. I think you'll want the date to be in the ordering as well.